# Incorporating javascript maps into Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

I am trying to incorporate Javascript google maps into my Angular 8 project in order to add more functionality than AGM. I have created a typings.d.ts file and included my javascript in the angular.json but i am still getting the error: ***'map' is declared but its value is never read.*** Here is my code...

**component.html**

```
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{apiKey}}&callback=initMap"
    async defer>
    </script>
    <script >
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**component.ts**

```
import * as map from 'map';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-maps',
  templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit {

  private apiKey = environment.googleMapsAPIkey;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**maps.js**

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module Map {
  export interface Main {
    map;
  }
}
declare var Map:Map.Main;
```

Comment: It says that imported 'map' is not used.
 import * as map from 'map';
Either use the map or remove the import statement if not required.

Comment: When I reference it, it says it cannot find the module

Comment: Are you able to display google maps div in your browser in normal without adding typings.d.ts file? By just including external script?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI that’s how I thought it should work too... I get no error when I do that though... pretty sure I referenced my apiKey correctly too in the sript src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code displated google maps in developer mode.

**html**

```
<div style="width: 1000px;height: 300px;" id="map"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor() { 

var dynamicScripts = ["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="apiKey"];

  for (var i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = dynamicScripts [i];
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }
}
initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
  });

 }
 ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout(()=>{ // 
     this.initMap();
   },2000);
 }
```

**Note** Instead of setTimeout we can use **promies.then()**.

Comment: thank you for the help, is the reason I couldnt load it normally because it is dynamic?

Comment: I think so. I will try to search more on this and will let you know..

Comment: So far everything seems to be working well except the clusterer package